# Both single and double quotes in a ruby array

Tags: ruby

I have an array with string values:

```
a = ["Customer name", "Address", "Qualification"]
```

Requirement is to make these string values enclosed in both single and double quotes like this:

```
a = ["'Customer name'", "'Address'", "'Qualification'"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes. The answer is yes. Or in other words: unclear what you're asking. What's the point of enclosing a string in both types of quotes...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ["Customer name", "Address", "Qualification"]
a.map { |i| "'#{i}'" } # =>  ["'Customer name'", "'Address'", "'Qualification'"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to say that you want to enclose the content of each string with single quotes, but it does not make sense to say that you want to have double quotes around it, that is part of the literal. But anyway,

```
a.map{|s| "'#{s}'"}
# => ["'Customer name'", "'Address'", "'Qualification'"]
```